# Non Negative integral solutions

Tags: combinatorics, systems-of-equations

So we know there is nice explanation for how to obtain the solutions of
$ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 +... x_r = n$  subject to conditions in title.  But what if we attach coefficients to these $x_i$  then problem becomes interesting as say the $x_1$ becomes $3x_1$ then that particular variable will only be able to take values multiples of 3. Then shifting that particular variable on the right and then solving as usual we can find no. of solutions and then sum up them for various values (multiples) it takes.  But it will involve calculation difficulties unless $r= 3$  now I was wondering about a easy solution to this problem. And what if more than one variable has it is coefficient not equal to one.

Answer (score 1):

If $a_n$ is the number of solutions non-negative integer solutions to $\alpha_1x_1+\dots+\alpha_rx_r=n$ for some integer coefficients $\alpha_i$, then its generating function $G(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0} a_n x^n$ is given by
$$ G(x)=(1-x^{\alpha_1})^{-1} \cdots (1-x^{\alpha_r})^{-1}.$$
This can be used to derive asymptotics of the number of such solutions, but I doubt that there is an exact formula for general weights.

Comment: Can you take a specific example and give solution? I am not aware of generating functions . if you solve a example it would help me understand this better. Does my question not qualify for a upvote?

Answer (score 1):

As Julian mentioned, generating functions are usually a good way to go. Alternatively, a we can take a programmatic approach and compute the number of solutions recursively. Let $T(k,n)$ denote the number of nonnegative integral solutions for given $c_i$ and $n$.
$$ T(k,n) = \textstyle \# \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^{k}c_ix_i = n \right\}$$
We can partition the solutions into those where $x_k = 0,1,2,\ldots$.
$$ 
\begin{array}{rcl}
T(k,n) &=& \textstyle \# \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}c_ix_i = n \right\} \\
&+& \textstyle \# \left\{ c_k +\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}c_ix_i = n \right\} \\
&+& \textstyle \# \left\{ 2c_k + \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}c_ix_i = n \right\} \\
&+& \ldots
\end{array}
$$
which gives us the recurrence relation
$$T(k,n) = \sum_{j=0}^{\left \lfloor n/c_i \right \rfloor} T(k-1, n-jc_k )$$
The only nonzero base case is $T(0,0)=1$. A memoizing or dynamic programming implementation will run in
$\sum \frac{n}{2}\left(\frac{n}{c_i} + 1\right)$ or more loosely $\mathcal{O}(k n^2$) time. The nice thing is that at the end you get more than the single value $T(k,n)$. In the process you also compute all values $T(i,m)$ for $i \leq k$ and $m \leq n$. By making a change of variables we can also generalize this method to work with bounds $\ell_i \leq x_i \leq \mu_i$.